# Assignment and random

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that repeatedly flips a coin until three heads in a row are seen.  Each time the coin is flipped, what is seen is displayed (H for heads, T for tails). When 3 heads in a row are flipped a congratulatory message is printed. 
eg.T T T H T H H H
Three heads in a row!

```
public static void threeHeads(){
  Random rnd=new Random();
    char c = (char) (rnd.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    for(int i=1;i<=c.
}
```

I am stuck inside for loops.How should I specify the number of times it will loop.Even if I declare 3 different char c,how can I convert it to the number of times to loop.I was thinking if I should find the ascii table to find which number is H and T to print these 2 out specially?Or a loop is redundant?

```
public static void threeHeads(){
  Random rnd=new Random();
    char c = (char) (rnd.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    if(c=='H' && c=='H' && c=='H'){
        System.out.println("Three heads in a row!");
    }
}
```

Another problem is assignment which is == and equals.
For a boolean value,i use ==
I understand that for strings,I should use equal.Then for a char character,what should I use?
eg.char=='y'
Am I right?

Comment: Because i am trying to call for random char(H for heads) and (T for tails).So i am having a loop to specify the number of times i want it to loop.

Comment: For chars you can use ==.

Comment: Mate, you have lots of answers below. Read them carefully and you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is a homework.

Instead of using `Random.nextInt`, use `Random.nextBoolean`.
Say **TAIL** is `false` and **HEAD** is `true`

You then need a counter of HEADS in a row, that is incremented when new **HEAD** is turned, and reset to `0` when **TAIL** is flipped.

Once that counter has a value of `3` you have an exit condition for your loop.

Answer (score 2):

1. The outcome of coin flip is binary. Match H to 1 and T to 0. You only generate these two numbers randomly.
2. Put a counter `cnt` in your loop which will set to 0 when it is T (0) and `cnt++` if it is H (1). Then you'll have to break out of the loop if `cnt > 2` (something like `if(cnt>2) break;`)
3. Don't forget that you need to regenerate random number each time you go through the loop. In your current code it is done only once.

I think these ideas should be enough to write your code.

Comment: your char assignment generates ONE random character. Every time you call 'c' it is still the same character which has been generated initially. You need to do rnd.nextInt (or better nextBoolean because your outcome is binary) multiple times (think of it as tossing the coin before looking at the outcome).

Answer (score 1):

In general, whenever you find yourself asking "How do i keep track of XXX", the answer is to declare a new variable. In your case, however, you can use the loop counter `i`:

Here is how i would approach this problem:

```
public static void threeHeads()
{
    Random rnd=new Random();
    char c; //no need to initialize the char

    //ostensibly, we will loop 3 times
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i ++)
    {
          c = rnd.nextBoolean() ? 'h' : 't'; /*get random char*/;

          if (c != 'h')
          {
               //but if we encounter a tails, reset the loop counter to -1
                             //that way it will be 0 next time the loop executes
               i = -1;
          }

          System.out.println(c);
     }
}
```

This way it will keep trying to loop three times until `c` is `'h'` every time.

To answer your question about `==` versus `equals()`:

You can always use `==` on primitive types (int, char, double, anything that is not an object). For objects (Strings, Double-with-a-capital D's, Lists), you are better off using `equals`. This is because `==` will test whether or not the objects are *exactly the same object* -- which is only true if they occupy the same location in memory. Nine times out of ten you are actually interested in checking whether or not the objects are *equivalent* and you don't care whether or not they are literally the same object. It is still a good idea to understand the details of this however, in case you encounter a situation where you do want to use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int head =0;
 int tail =1;
 public static void threeHeads(){
      Random rnd=new Random();
      int headsSeen = 0;
       while(headsSeen < 3){
         int res = rnd.nextInt(1); //returns 1 or 0
         if (res == head){
              headsSeen ++; 
         }else{
              headsSeen = 0; //there was a tail so reset counter
         }
           }
         ///At this point three heads seen in a row
}
```

Comment: `new Random()` does *not* return the same sequence every time. If you want a distinct sequence each time, using the no-arg constructor is indeed the correct way to use it. Specifying the seed should only be done to "replay" a sequence.